# C++ template argument limited to classes (not basic types)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

Is it possible specify a template argument, that would never match to a basic type, such as an int? I'm heavily fighting ambiguities. So for example:

```
template<class T> void Function(const T& x) { SetString(x.GetString()); };
```

That would work only if there's a method GetString in T, but if the compiler sees this function, it tries to uses it even if T is just int for example.

Comment: I think `std::enable_if` is what you're looking for.

Comment: What do you want to happen if someone tries to write `Function(35);`? Is there something else that you want it to do in the `int` case?

Comment: `std::enable_if` in combination with `std::is_fundamental` or `std::is_arithmetic`

Comment: It's unfortunate that C++20 isn't an option. Concepts would solve this extremely simply with a requirement for `{ t.GetString() } -> std::convertable_to<std::string>`

Comment: maybe, instead of disable the function for basic types, you can enable it if and only if `x` has a `GetString()` method. Should be enough `template <typename T> auto Function (T const & x) -> decltype( x.GetString(), void()) { SetString(x.GetString()); };`

Comment: @max66 exactly. I was thinking the [same thing](https://godbolt.org/z/P1Pses87o).

Comment: @max66 That would be especially awesome, but how to write that exactly? MSVC doesn't seem to like that "->" thingy. I actually have no idea what that is, seems like a lamba definition. Damn, I'm rusty :D

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek which version of MSVC are you using because [it works when I test it?](https://godbolt.org/z/os6PM58ze), also [C++20 concepts example](https://godbolt.org/z/6nWo35Eqj)

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek - I've written it exactly as should works... well... maybe there is an unuseful semicolon at the end, but should works anyway. Maybe your compiler doesn't support C++11? Or there is a constness problem? Give me some minutes and I expand my comment in an answer with a full compiling example.

Comment: @Mgetz That version works, great solution, thanks!

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek note I'm not submitting my C++20 version because the question is tagged c++17. For solutions that solve that you'd need to look to max66's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method 1

You can use `std::enable_if` as shown below:

##### C++11

```
//this function template will not be used with fundamental types
template<class T> typename std::enable_if<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>::type Function(const T& x) 
{ 
    SetString(x.GetString()); 
    
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/V_xA5a0AV)

##### C++17

```
template<class T> typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental_v<T>> Function(const T& x) 
{ 
    SetString(x.GetString()); 
    
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/_ca1bsXgX)

#### Method 2

We can make use of [**SFINAE**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). Here we use `decltype` and the **comma operator** to define the return type of the function template.

```
//this function template will work if the class type has a const member function named GetString
template <typename T> auto Function (T const & x) -> decltype( x.GetString(), void()) 
{ 
    SetString(x.GetString());   
};
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/TkCKvUK7N)

Here we've used *trailing return type syntax* to specify the return type of the function template.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem i that `int` doesn't support a `GetString()` method, maybe instead of disable the function for fundamental types, you could enable it if (and only if) the template type has a `GetString() const` method accepting a call without arguments.

Observe that `GetString()` must be `const`, because `Function()` receive a `const` reference, so you can call `GetString()` inside `Function()` only if `GetString()` is a `const` method.

The following is a full compiling example. Observe the failure in the `bar1` and `bar2` cases

```
#include <string>

void SetString (std::string const &) 
{ }

struct foo // class with a conformat GetString method
{ std::string GetString () const { return "abc"; } };

struct bar1 // class with a not conformant (not const) GetString method
{ std::string GetString () { return "123"; } };

struct bar2 // class with a not conformant (require a int) GetString method
{ std::string GetString (int) const { return "123"; } };

struct bar3 // class without a GetString method
{ };


template <typename T>
auto Function (T const & x) -> decltype( x.GetString(), void())
{ SetString(x.GetString()); }

int main()
{
  Function(foo{}); // compile

  // Function(bar1{}); // compilation error (GetString isn't const)
  // Function(bar2{}); // compilation error (GetString require a int)
  // Function(bar3{}); // compilation error (no GetString method)
  // Function(0);      // compilation error (no GetString method)
}
```

Comment: Could you point me out to some resource about what the "-> decltype" does? Seems like an intriguing concept.

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek it's just a [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) (see def 2)

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek `->` is called(in this context)  [*trailing return type syntax*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) as explained in my answer. In the above mentioned link, there is an example `template<class T, class U> auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u);`. You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64098776/15545927).

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek - See the link that Mgets suggest. Anyway, the idea is that the compiler detect, with `decltype()`, the type of the call `x.GetString()`; if isn't a valid expression, the function isn't enabled; if it's a valid expression, the comma operator discard the type of `x.GetString()` and return (that is: say that `Function()` return) the type of `void()`, that is `void`. It's pure [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)

Comment: @mrzacekmrzacek - If you don't like the trailing return type, you can avoid it writing something as `template <typename T> decltype( std::declval<T const>().GetString(), void()) Function (T const & x) { ... }`. That is: you can place `decltype()` before the name of the function. Unfortunately, in that case, you can't use `x` (the compiler doesn't know what `x` is, before the name of the function) so you have to use `std::declval()` to simulate an object of type `T const`.

Comment: Also [c++20 concepts version requiring `GetString() const`](https://godbolt.org/z/Gsar9W67d)

Comment: Thanks for the info folks! Time to learn about sfinae